# Custom viewcell like imagecell xaml?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How would i go about creating an identical "imagecell" but custom? The problem i am having with regular "imagecell" is that the image is hardcoded to 60x60 ..

I am pulling favicon from url's which means that a favicon from 16x16 to 60x60 will have super low quality. The alternative i have here is to change the size of the image but yet again, not doable in "imagecell" as it is hard coded.

Is there any website with different custom cells that i can look on or do anyone have the code for an identical imagecell view.

this is the code i am currently using.

```
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell Text="{Binding mainSite}" TextColor="Black" Detail="{Binding link}" ImageSource="{Binding image}"></ImageCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: this is how the output is from the XAML code]

Answer (score 1):

you could easily build a similar UI with a ViewCell using nested StackLayouts, or alternatively a Grid

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image />
  <StackLayout>
    <Label />
    <Label />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I am really bad with XAML code. I really like the imagecell view but yet again, image might be to big but i also want to add an (i) clickable logo on the right. For getting like info about the item in the cell.

Comment: my project is quite big aswell so going from a XAML code where Listview is not present is not preferable :)